# SQL Total Sale calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum

I have a sale table includes purchases/returns/exchanges
Sample:

```
--------**saleTbl**------------
CustID | DOP | SKU | Price
111 | 11/05/12 | 001 | 45.99
222 | 11/20/12 | 001 | 45.99
111 | 11/06/12 | 002 | 40.95
111 | 11/06/12 | 001 | -45.99
111 | 11/19/12 | 004 | 50.00
222 | 11/25/12 | 003 | 20.99
111 | 12/01/12 | 002 | -40.95
111 | 12/01/12 | 003 | 20.99
```

Criteria is: find total for each customer during 11/05/12 - 11/20/12. If customer exchanged the item that was purchased during that time and purchase with the same day will be count.
The expected result is:

```
CustID | DOP | Price
222 | 11/20/12 | 45.99
111 | 12/01/12 | 70.99
```

I have tried to get the total but of course it is not right:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [num_cp] AS 'Member Id'
      ,MAX([dop]) AS 'Date'
      ,SUM([price]) AS 'Point'
  FROM [Mailing_List].[dbo].[UGG_DoublePoint]
  WHERE [num_cp] IN
  (
    SELECT [num_cp]
    FROM [Mailing_List].[dbo].[UGG_DoublePoint]
    GROUP BY [num_cp]
    HAVING SUM([price]) >0
  )
  --AND 
  AND [dop] BETWEEN '11/05/12' AND '11/20/12'
  GROUP BY [num_cp]
```

Please help! Thanks everyone.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: If the period is between 11/05/12 - 11/20/12 why in your expected result is a 12/01/12 entry listed?  Can you elaborate or fix the expected output.

Comment: @Brian: it will get the latest date of the item exchanged. How do I edit my question?

Comment: @tkvo then latest date for 222 should be 11/25/12 right?

Comment: @rs: 222 item purchased on 11/25/12 would not count. item exchanged of 111 was on 12/01/12, this is count as exchanged item

Comment: @tkvo how do you distinguish between purchased and exchanged?

Comment: @rs: if customer made return then purchase on the same day = exchange

Comment: @spandy item 003 considers as an exchange of item 002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your query to this

```
; WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CustID, DOP) Row_Cnt
    FROM TEST
), CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM CTE
    WHERE [dop] BETWEEN '11/05/12' AND '11/20/12'
), CTE3 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE price > 0
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE price < 0 
    and SKU IN (SELECT SKU FROM CTE2 WHERE Price > 0)
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM CTE
    WHERE row_cnt > 1 and DOP IN (
    SELECT max(A.dop) d FROM CTE A
    INNER JOIN CTE2 B ON A.CustID = B.CustID AND A.SKU = B.SKU
    )
 )
SELECT Custid, max(dop) dateid, sum(price) Price
from cte3
group by custid;
```

Check [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42c04/14)

Comment: could you help me again with the same query but no need to count the exchange item any more, just subtract whatever return. Here is the SQL Fiddle link:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3c03/1. The expected result is Total=482.33

Comment: could you help again with the request above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. It basically filters out any returns from the result set by use of a left join.

NOTE: There would be an issue with this in the case that someone purchased/returned multiple SKUs of the same thing on the same day.

```
select pur.CustId, sum(pur.price) TotalPrice
from test pur
left join test ret
  on pur.custid = ret.custid
   and pur.dop = ret.dop
   and pur.sku = ret.sku
   and pur.price = (-1 * ret.price)
where pur.dop between '11/05/2012' AND '11/20/2012'
  and ret.price is null
group by  pur.CustId
```